# How to fix issues with 'The SSH connection was unexpectedly closed by the remote end'?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, vagrant

My configuration:

- dedicated server (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) used for Jenkins (2.7.1) only,
- over 100+ Jenkins jobs, each invoking vagrant instances to AWS ([Vagrantfile](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM/blob/49b6c10127adfba0d57c027eca3498c3172d82bf/Vagrantfile)),
- each job (provision script) may take 1-2h to run,
- most of the server config files (such as SSH) have default system configuration.

When I run multiple Jenkins instances at the same time, they're more likely to fail with this error:

```
00:00:00.774 + vagrant up --no-provision --destroy-on-error --provider=aws
00:00:09.635 Bringing machine 'MT-aws' up with 'aws' provider...
...
00:01:16.498     MT-aws: Running: inline script
...
00:01:26.415 ==> MT-aws: + echo
00:01:26.415 ==> MT-aws: + sleep 20
00:01:26.427 The SSH connection was unexpectedly closed by the remote end. This
00:01:26.427 usually indicates that SSH within the guest machine was unable to
00:01:26.427 properly start up. Please boot the VM in GUI mode to check whether
00:01:26.427 it is booting properly.
00:01:26.625 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Facts:

- the provisioning script fails at random places (no specific code right before the fail),
- server is not overloaded and has plenty of free RAM and access to Gbit network,
- the more jobs I run in parallel, they've more chances to fail,
- re-running the same job individually usually works fine,
- default settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, no `~/.ssh/config` for Jenkins.

---

How can I fix the above issue with SSH being *unexpectedly closed*?

Do I need to increase some SSH timeout settings or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Modify setting as follows:

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```

Where,

> **ClientAliveInterval**: Sets a timeout interval in seconds (30) after which if no data has been received from the client, sshd will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default is 0, indicating that these messages will
>   not be sent to the client. This option applies to protocol version 2 only.
>
> **ClientAliveCountMax**: Sets the number of client alive messages (5) which may be sent without sshd receiving any messages back from the client. If this threshold is reached while client alive messages are being sent, sshd will disconnect the client, terminating the session.

Close and save the file, then restart `sshd`, e.g.:

```
# /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

or:

```
# service sshd restart
```

---

Another option is enable `ServerAliveInterval` in the client’s (your workstation) `ssh_config` file, e.g.

```
# vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Then append/modify values as follows:

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

Where,

> **ServerAliveInterval**: Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.

In above example, `ServerAliveInterval` is set to 15 and `ServerAliveCountMax` is left at the 3, if the server becomes unresponsive, ssh will disconnect after approximately 45 seconds. Again this option applies to protocol version 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, as suggested by [Chris Roberts](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7681#issuecomment-266033097), is to add a SSH [`keep_alive`](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/7fa9892b754b5aef7877a10a87cf875089c5f92c) line to `Vagrantfile` e.g.

```
config.vm.ssh.keep_alive = true
```

This will send SSH keep-alive packets every 5 seconds by default to keep connections alive.

See: [`config.ssh` related settings](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) for further information.

Comment: This did not work for our Vagrant machines.  Getting an error like `* The following settings shouldn't exist: ssh`.  Tried putting it in different locations but nothing worked.